# zsh survive glob failure

Tags: error-handling, zsh, gitignore, glob

I have checked out a project, the project contains a `.gitignore` file.

The contents of this file are like so

```
vx1% head .gitignore 
./deps
/*.exe
/*.la
/.auto
.libs
ChangeLog
Makefile
Makefile.in
aclocal.m4
autom4te.cache
```

### I want to

- read the file line by line
- for each line read, list the actual files that are being ignored
- finally I want to tweak the script to delete those files

The reason for wanting to do this - is that I don't trust the project Makefile to fully clean up it's generated files.

### Notes

As you can see, the .gitignore uses some globs that I need to modify before running the commands, otherwise the glob will resolve to my root directory.

#### What I already know

#### To dynamically evaluate an arbitrary string as a glob pattern

DYN="*.c"

print $~DYN

#### To strip the leading /, if it exists

DYN="/*.c"

print ${~DYN/#//}

#### What I've got

cat .gitignore | while read i; do echo $i ;  print ${~i/#//} ; done

### The problem

The first glob failure that this loop encounters, it terminates with error

`zsh: no matches found: *.exe`

### What I want

The 'script' should keep going through each line of the file, trying each line in turn.

### I answered this myself, answer is below

Comment: I know, but those curmudgeons wouldn't let me post the solution for 8 hours - wasn't going to sit there waiting !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the answer on the [zsh mailing list](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2008/msg01133.html), in typical Zsh fashion - it's very simple when you know how, and impossible otherwise.

```
print *.nosuchextension(N)
```

The (N) glob parameter prevents raising an error on match failure.

Comment: Just a comment to say "Thanks!" and a bit more.  The link to the ZSH mailing list that you posted provides a link to reference that explains `(N)`.  It means **sets the NULL_GLOB option for the current pattern**.  Wanted to point out that this would have a negative effect in some cases e.g., `gawk -f script *.csv(N)` would cause the script to indefinitely wait for interactive input.